# How to use Gauss–Hermite quadrature for approximate an integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)dx$

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods, improper-integrals

Gauss–Hermite quadrature can be used for integral of the form

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\exp\left({-\frac{(x-k)^2}{2a^2}}\right)dx$$

Notice that it integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

But I want to approximate an integral

$$\int_0^\infty x^n\exp\left({-\frac{(x-k)^2}{2a^2}}-x\right)dx$$

Notice that it integrate from $0$ to $\infty$.

It seems to be more complicated if I change variable $y=\ln x$.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is $f(x) = x^n \exp(-x)$ for $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise a possibility? If it isn't then it could be interesting to include a few words about this in your question.